# Is this a context-free language?

Tags: context-free-grammar

this is the Language

```
L = {a^i b^j a^i b^k | i, j, k >= 0}
```

Then, I can to try a grammar for this Language:

```
S -> ABCD  
A -> a | aA | lambda  
B -> b | bB | lambda  
C -> a | aC | lambda  
D -> b | bD | lambda
```

It's context-free...is it right the grammar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grammar allows `aaba`, which it shouldn't, as there should always be a even number of `a`s:

```
ABCD
aABCD
aaBCD
aabCD
aabaD
aaba
```

A correct answer would be:

```
Start → A B

A → a A a | B
B → bB | ε
```

- `B` generates any number of `b`s (including none).
- `A` is a sequence of `a`, followed by `B`, followed by the same number of `a`